# How can I remove all <a> tags from an HTML block, and leave the rest?

Tags: iphone, regex, parsing, uiwebview

I have a bunch of html that I am prepping for display in a UIWebView for an iPad app I am working on. The HTML has a number of different tags that I am fine with, but there are a bunch of a-tags with irrelevant links that I need to have removed. I am going to be putting this text into a sqlite db.

What is the best way to get all of the  a-tags out of my HTML text? I figure regex is the best way, but I just don't get regex very well. A blog online mentioned that this regex is the way to remove all tags:

```
 <(.|\n)*?>
```

So what would I need to do in order to adjust that to be a-tag specific? Or is there a different approach that I should take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex you need is:

```
<a.*?>|</a>
```

this matches both `<a{something}>` OR `</a>` - the tags you need to remove. I don't know about the ObjectiveC regex functions though, see Ron's post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSString *str = @"Turn left onto <a>Sri Krishna Nagar Rd</a><div class=\"google_note\">Pass by <b landmarkid=\"0x39ed58475c24020f:0x170a2130a5880d5a\" class=\"dir-landmark\">California Academy of Visual Effects</b> <div class=\"dirseg-sub\">(on the left)</div>\n</div>";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r\\n" withString:@""];
NSRange r;
while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your help! I realized that SO had edited my post to hide the a-tags, so it didn't make any sense. All I need gone are the a-tags, it seems like your code took out all the tags. Can anything be tweaked to just remove all the a-tags? Thanks again for your help!